# How to use get_fields() to access M2M field values

Tags: django, django-models

I am using get_fields() to produce a dict of all model field names and values:

```
def get_model_fields(self, obj, fields):

    model_fields = {}

    for f in self.model._meta.get_fields(include_hidden=True):
         value = getattr(obj, f.name)
         model_fields.append({
                        'label': f.verbose_name
                        'name': f.name,
                        'help_text': f.help_text,
                        'value': value,
                        'class': str(f.__class__)})

 return model_fields
```

This works well except for ManyToMany fields, where the `label`, `name`, `help_text` and `class` all display fine, but the value returns `[modelname].None`, despite it containing values.

For example:

models.py

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
     m2m_field = models.ManyToManyField(...)
     char_field = models.CharField()
```

views.py

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        view_data = []
        view_data = get_model_fields(self, context['object'], self.fields)
        context['view_data'] = view_data

        return context
```

template.html

```
{% for f in view_data %}
  {{f.label}}
  {{f.value}}
{% endfor %}
```

This will return the label and value correctly for `char_field` but only label for `m2m_field` and the value as `MyModel.None`.

How can I add the values of the ManyToMany field to this function?

Comment: Could you elaborate more in depth which fields aren't shown and how does your usage look etc..

Comment: Yes, I have updated with a more verbose example. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that a Many to Many field can store multiple values, but you're treating it as if it only stores one.

For example, let's say you have a single object in a queryset, with one M2M field called "names":

```
qs = <QuerySet [<MyModelName: ModelObject>]>
```

This won't work:

```
for field in qs:
   print(field.names)

appname.ParentModel.none  #result is .none
```

But if you do this, you'll get the one or more values of the many to many field:

```
for field in qs:
   for n in field.names.all():
       print(n)

ObjectName1
ObjectName2
ObjectName3, etc...
```

Bottom line, you're going to need to loop through the M2M values.